Trace formula of totally ramified $\mathbb Z_p$ extension
I am reading Fontaine and Yi Ouyang's "Theory of p-adic Galois representations" (reference here). This is a question on page 38 of chapter 1 on totally ramified $\mathbb Z_p$-extension.

I am having trouble understanding the last two lines of the proof--why out of sudden the Trace relationship give the inequality?
$$
v_K(p^{-1}Tr_{K_{n+1}/K_n}(x))\ge v_K(x)-ap^{-n},
$$
and how does the corollary follow from the last inequality in the proof? since it was on $K_n/K$ instead of just $K_{n+1}/K_n$.
(For reference, corollary 79 is quoted below)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It should be mentioned that the $K_n$ are fully ramified extensions of $K$ of degree $p^n$ and $e=v_K(p)$ is the absolute ramification index of $K$. From the equality obtained by Corollary 1.79 we get $$v_{K_n}(\operatorname{Tr}_{K_{n+1}/K_n}(x))\geq\Big[\frac{v_{K_{n+1}}(x)+d}{p}\Big]$$
Note that $v_{K_n}=p^nv_K$ and $d=v_{K_{n+1}}(\mathcal D_{K_{n+1}/K_n})=p^{n+1}e+pb_n$. Then we get\begin{align*}
v_{K}(p^{-1}\operatorname{Tr}_{K_{n+1}/K_n}(x))&=v_{K}(\operatorname{Tr}_{K_{n+1}/K_n}(x))-e\\
&=p^{-n}v_{K_n}(\operatorname{Tr}_{K_{n+1}/K_n}(x))-e\\
&\geq p^{-n}\Big[\frac{v_{K_{n+1}}(x)+d}{p}\Big]-e\\
&=p^{-n}\Big[\frac{p^{n+1}v_{K}(x)+p^{n+1}e+pb_n}{p}\Big]-e\\
&\geq p^{-n}\Big(\frac{p^{n+1}v_{K}(x)+p^{n+1}e+pb_n}{p}-1\Big)-e\\
&=v_K(x)+(b_n-1)p^{-n}
\end{align*}
and $b_n-1$ is bounded independent of $n$. This shows the inequality. To see that the corollary follows from this use induction, transitivity of the trace and the geometric series.

That's very helpful--thank you!
